# Excel Addin Button

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I am new to Excel addin programming. I created an Excel addin for Excel 2010 in C# which will create button in every sheet of workbook.

Can some one tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoWorksheet = activeWorksheet.GetVstoObject(Globals.Factory);
Excel.Range selection = vstoWorksheet.Range[2, 2];
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button button = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
button.Tag = vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(button,selection, "Click"); button.Name = "Click";
button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
button.Text = "Click";
```

Comment: Microsoft has a whole website about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx

Comment: <code>Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet =Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoWorksheet = activeWorksheet.GetVstoObject(Globals.Factory);
 Excel.Range selection = vstoWorksheet.Range[2, 2];
 Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button button = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
button.Tag = vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(button,selection, "Click");
 button.Name = "Click";
 button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
 button.Text = "Click";
</code>

Can some one tell me what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem:

```
button.Tag = vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(button,selection, "Click");
```

Should be:

```
vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(button,selection, "Click");
```